# Working in Eclipse IDE, values that should equal not equal

Tags: java, eclipse

I am reasonably experienced with programming, but not specifically in Java. I am coming across the following error when working in eclipse. My code is the following:

[image: My code]

I have used the debug function, and it reports that carbonPrefix is pent, but that carbon stays at 0 throughout. Like I said, I am a novice to Java and Eclipse, so I may not be using the debug function to it's full extent.

For anybody that's interested, this the start of code where you input the name of an alkane and it tells you the formula. It worked in Javascript and I'm just trying to translate it into Java.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Please put the code in text form and make sure it's complete.

Comment: `==` for objects (including String) tests for *identity*, not equality. Two different Strings with the same content are not "the same thing', because they use different regions of memory for their content. See Jim Lewis' link for what do to instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use

```
carbonPrefix.equals("pent");
```

in java `==` operator used to compare  two `object references` and the method `equals()` is used to compare two `strings` to determine whether they are equal or not.